# Google sign in intent privacy policy not open

Tags: android, google-authentication

I am following this document
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin#java_1

The app already in Google play and contain privacy policy link Google developer console.

But when I click on privacy policy in auth dialog I have the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to add `privacy policy` link and `terms and condition` link in `google developer console` under `APIs & Services` -> `OAuth consent screen` -> `App domain`

Create new OAuth consent if not created already else just click on `edit app` option under `OAuth consent screen`.